# Making a double query ( Find inside a Find) in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to query a document. here's its schema

```
{
_id,
notes: [{_id: 243234,
text: "hey"},
_id, 421123,
text: "hi"}
]
}
```

I want to first find the document by _id and then find the value of 'text' on notes[1].

Using this, I can find the actual document but how can I find the object inside notes array? I have to find and update the 'text' inside note.

```
socket.on("individualnote edit", function(data) {
    rooms.find({ _id: data.roomId}, function( err, doc) {
      if (err) {
            console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
      }
      console.log(doc);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`positional $`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator to find and update an element within a sub document array.

> The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

```
rooms.findOneAndUpdate({
  _id: _id,
  'notes.text': 'hey'
}, {
  '$set': {
    'notes.$.text': 'new text'
  }
}).then(() => {
  console.log('Success');
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('err', err.stack);
});
```